# Difference between element, item and entry when it comes to programming?

Tags: naming

Naming variables is quite important and being a non-native English speaker I wonder what the difference would be for using element, item and entry to name things within data structures or variables/parameters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let us start with the *plain English* meaning of each of these:

1. **Element**: a part or aspect of something `abstract`, especially one that is essential or characteristic.

   > Thus, they can be thought of logically connected atomic parts of a whole. E.g. Elements(Nodes) of a Tree, Elements of a `HTML` code(Opening tag, `InnerHtml` content and Closing tag)
2. **Item**: an individual article or unit, especially one that is part of a list, collection, or set.

   > I prefer this when the thing are logically independent like Items in a Shopping cart, Items in a bag, etc
3. **Entry**: an item written or printed in a diary, list, ledger, or reference book.

   > I usually use this for tables like Hash Table or Accounts(Transaction entry) or Records(recording entries in sales, etc.)

Now we can't refer the **items** in a bag(considered as an Object in Object oriented paradigm) as entries or elements(probably not **elements** because the **items** as not constituents of the *bag* itself).

However, in some cases like an array we can use the **element** or **item** or **entry** interchangeably too **:)**

Comment: What about entry vs record?

Answer (score 1):

Had to think on this for a few minutes, interesting :)

Note I'm not a native English speaker either so my opinions are just that, opinions.

I use 'element' for things that have some connection with each other, like nodes in a graph or tree. I use 'item' for individual elements in a list (i.e. that don't necessarily have a connection to each other). I don't use 'entry' because I don't like it in this context, but it's just a matter of preference.

Since I'm primarily a C# dev, this is apparent in .Net's naming too: a `List<T>` has Items, but WPF building blocks in XAML, or XML tags, are Elements (and many more similar examples); that's probably at least part of the reason why I formed this habit.

I don't think there would be anything very wrong with switching things around though; it would certainly be understandable enough from my point of view.